# Best approach for Java/Maven/JPA/Hibernate build with multiple database vendor support?

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, jpa, build, hbm2ddl

I have an enterprise application that uses a single database, but the application needs to support **mysql**, **oracle**, and **sql*server** as installation options.

To try to *remain portable* we are using **JPA annotations** with **Hibernate** as the implementation.  We also have a test-bed instance of each database running for development.

The app is building nicely in **Maven** and I've played around with the **hibernate3-maven-plugin** and can auto-generate DDL for a given database dialect.

What is the best way to approach this so that individual developers can easily test against all three databases and our Hudson based CI server can build things properly.

More specifically:

1. I thought the **hbm2ddl** goal in the [hibernate3-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/hibernate3-maven-plugin) would just generate a schema file, *but apparently it connects to a live database and attempts to create the schema*.  Is there a way to have this *just create the schema file* for each database dialect *without* connecting to a database?
2. If the **hibernate3-maven-plugin** insists on actually creating the database schema, is there a way to have it drop the database and recreate it before creating the schema?
3. I am thinking that each developer (and the Hudson build machine) should have their own separate database on each database server.  Is this typical?
4. Will developers have to run Maven three times... once for each database vendor?  If so, how do I merge the results on the build machine?
5. There is a **hbm2doc** goal within hibernate3-maven-plugin.  It seems overkill to run this three times... I gotta believe it'd be nearly identical for each database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Is there a way to have this just create the schema file for each database dialect without connecting to a database?

Set `export` to `false`. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <components>
      <component>
        <name>hbm2ddl</name>
        <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
      </component>
    </components>
    <componentProperties>
      <export>false</export><!-- do not export to the database -->
      <drop>true</drop>
      <configurationfile>src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
      <outputfilename>my_schema.ddl</outputfilename>
    </componentProperties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> 2) If the hibernate3-maven-plug insists on actually creating the database schema, is there a way to have it drop the database and recreate it before creating the schema?

See above. But just in case, for this set `update` to `true`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <components>
      <component>
        <name>hbm2ddl</name>
        <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
      </component>
    </components>
    <componentProperties>
      <export>true</export>
      <update>true</update><!-- update the schema -->
      <drop>true</drop>
      <configurationfile>src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
      <outputfilename>my_schema.ddl</outputfilename>
    </componentProperties>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
      <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
      <version>10.5.3.0_1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

> 3) I am thinking that each developer (and the hudson build machine) should have their own separate database on each database server. Is this typical?

Yes, and I consider this as a best practices (see [Use one database instance per developer](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/bestpractices.html#onedbperdev)).

> 4) Will developers have to run Maven three times...once for each database vendor? If so, how do I merge the results on the build machine?

Yes, very likely and I would use profiles for each database. On the build machine, I would [build a matrix project](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+matrix+project).

> 5) There is a hbm2doc goal within hibernate3-maven-plugin. It seems overkill to run this three times...I gotta believe it'd be nearly identical for each database.

I'm not used to this tool but I guess there might be some little variation in the output (e.g. with the primary key generation). I would generate the schema documentation for each database but at release time only (there is certainly no need to run that at each build).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The export=false setting did the trick.  Its a bit frustrating that the hibernate3-maven-plugin documentation is so poor.

Also thanks for the tip on the Hudson build matrix  it looks like just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @HDave Yes, the documentation is not its biggest strength (and sadly there are some little discrepancies with the corresponding ant tasks).