# Standard Workflow when working with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, workflow

I am currently trying to wrap my head around working with JPA. I can't help but feel like I am missing something or doing it the wrong way. It just seems forced so far.

What I think I know so far is that their are couple of ways to work with JPA and tools to support this.

- You can do everything in Java using annotations, and let JPA (whatever implementation you decide to use) create your schema and update it when changes are made.
- You can use a tool to reverse engineer you database and generate the entity classes for you. When the schema is updated you have to regenerate these classes, or manually update them.

There seems to be drawbacks to both, and benefits to both (as with all things). **My question is in an ideal situation what is the standard workflow with JPA?** Most schemas will require updates during the maintenance phase and especially during the development phase, so how is this handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not always a good approach to generate the DB schema from the annotated entities. Although in theory it sounds great - in practice often the generated schema is not optimal and would not satisfy and experienced DBA.

The approach that I follow in my workflow is to create the entities and db schema separately, while still using a pretty intelligent tool for the schema creating - either something like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org), that is database agnostic, supports revisions, rollbacks, etc... or a custom baked migration tool that simply runs heavily optimized db specific sql scripts.

It probably sounds to you less than ideal, but I can assure it gets the jobs done and keep your schema related code consistent since, as grigory pointed out - not everything related to the database can be generated from the entities anyways.

I can, however, be useful to generate the schema from the entities for the test database against which unit and integration tests are being run. Assuming you're using say PostgreSQL is production you might decide to speed things up for the unit tests running some embedded in-memory database like H2 which gets created from the entities before the tests are started and disappears automatically(since it was in-memory) after the tests finish executing. This is a very common practice.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Liquibase. And while it does not seem ideal, it makes sense and pretty much verifies what I thought. We are using Oracle, and right now have Oracle XE on a dev machines that we are using to run our tests. I'm going to have to look into H2 and see if that is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

As usual the answer is it depends...

Ideal approach (in ideal world) would probably be your 1st option: maintain everything using JPA annotations and forward engineer database artifacts using utility tool (e.g. use [Hibernate Maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832001/best-approach-for-java-maven-jpa-hibernate-build-with-multiple-database-vendor-su)).

It depends on the level of support for your database artifacts - not everything either belongs or suitable for annotations. That is why my projects usually use parallel maintenance for both and using unit tests to keep them in sync.

It also depends on resources available. If you have a dedicated DBA who is responsible for your database then delegating maintenance to her would make sense.

Other consideration is how much database development is really done in JPA. Are there also stored procedures or other non-JPA applications that use the same back-end, or maybe you just integrate with other team's database...

Comment: We do have a dedicated DBA and that was why going the 1st route seemed wrong. Thanks for the answer, it makes me more comfortable with the path we are taking.

Comment: First route would be too difficult, it has to be a mix of the two I find because it's not possible to do a few things in standards only JPA such as non-unique indexes

Answer (score 1):

If this is an existing application, I would check what you have existing, if the database structure complex as can be seen with the DDL and the DDL shows significant logic is being done on the database itself, then you are better off using plain SQLs and let the DBA maintain your data structures.  JPA does not really lend well when the database structures are already complicated and there is no business benefit to use JPA at that point.

What needs to happen is a project to migrate to JPA.  There are a few advantages to that:

- Business Logic is removed from the database layer (which is harder to scale horizontally) to the application tier.
- Java developers are generally cheaper compared to a DBA.  Though you still need someone who can do both database thinking and Java thinking to do this properly and that's more rare.
- By reducing the database to become as simple datastore, you can break yourself from vendor lock-in.
- If done right, you can have a different database for development (can be DB2 Express C which is free) and have a more robust database for your integration and production environments (e.g. DB/2 for zOS).  This allows you to be able to have more developers without worrying about licensing costs as much.

As for schemas being generated and such, there are actually four workflows that can occur:

1. For design, an Object-Relational (rather than an Entity-Relational) diagram serves as a contract between the application team and the database team.  The end result is the JPA objects will run in the physical data structure that the DBA sets.
2. For Java application development, just let each developer have their own database and let them blow it up as much as they want.  The JPA code will generate the schemas for you.
3. For database development, the generated schemas and class diagrams are passed onto review by the DBA to see where performance can be improved upon.  Specifically they are there to specify the indices which are not available in the JPA standard since it is not cross database.  They are also there to set up the table spaces and all the access controls and schemas for the development, but at least the gist of the structure can be taken away from them and passed onto the application team which gives the application team more flexibility to adapt to changes.  What would normally happen is the DBA just includes some generated SQL and then have alters to add additional columns and others that would be used for other purposes outside of the application (the JPA structure needs only what is needed by the application, it does not need to map one-to-one 100% to the database)
4. For migration, the DBA needs to do a differential analysis between the two schemas.  There's a program called dbsolo (not free) that can do it with most databases.  However, if things were done in JPA, the structures are simpler since in theory there is no longer any business logic on the database thus reducing the complexity of data migrations due to upgrades.

The net of it is you can't just say you're using JPA without involving the whole delivery team which will have to include the DBA willing to relinquish control and ownership of the structure of the data to the application team, but still be part of the design and reviews.